# Python Replacing String with Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm new to python so I don't really know a lot in this topic.

I have a function which gets item type, I have three types: A, B and C.

My initial approach was to pass item type as string, for example:

```
def my_function (item_type):
    if item_type == 'A': ...
```

But this is a bad approach, what are the alternatives? maybe class, but how to pass it to function

Comment: Are they classes? If so you can pass them directly

Comment: Can you clarify on the 'types' A B C? Are they custom types?

Comment: @TerryA like colors red green and blue. what are your suggestions?

Comment: I think you're looking for [enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Comment: Now we know what your types are, what is in the `...`? How does that vary depending on `item_type`?

Comment: @Anonymous12358 thanks, how to check the enum? for example how to check if it's green or red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than working with strings, use enums. For example:

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour(Enum):
    RED = 0
    GREEN = 1
    BLUE = 2
```

If the colours need to be distinct then just make sure that the values assigned are all different.

Then you might have a function like this:

```
def func(colour):
    match colour:
        case Colour.RED:
            pass
        case Colour.GREEN:
            pass
        case Colour.BLUE:
            pass
```

Of course, the enum might be wrapped in some other class but this should get you started

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking instances of classes then you can use `isinstance` or check using the `type` function

```
class A:
   pass

a = A()
print(isinstance(a,A))  # this is the preferred method
print(type(a) == A)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
True
```

---

If you are checking the classes themselves then you can do a straight comparison.

```
class A:
    pass

print(A == A)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
```

---

If you are checking subclasses then you can use `issubclass` function

```
class Parent:
    pass

class A(Parent):
    pass

class B(Parent):
    pass

print(issubclass(A, Parent))
print(issubclass(B, Parent))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
True
```

---

---

**Update** from the question in your comment if you want to consolidate classes you could do something like this:

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

red = Color('red')
blue = Color('blue')
green = Color('green')

print(red.color)
print(blue.color)
print(green.color)
print(isinstance(red, Color))
print(isinstance(green, Color))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'red'
'blue'
'green'
True
True
```

Comment: Do I need 3 classes A,B,C? but all types are types of same object... they should be one

Comment: See my comment please, I still believe no need for 3 classes. For example I mean Red, Green and Blue (all colors)

Comment: Do you need all 3?   It depends on what you plan to use them for.

Comment: @log  see the bottom of my answer... all three are not needed

Answer (score 0):

The good design usually avoids using `isinstance()` or `type()` calls.
If you need some class-specific logic you better encapsulate it in a class itself. Please refer to:
https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism